# What is the simplest way to differentiate between Windows versions?

Tags: c#, windows

How do I know programmatically whether my OS is Longhorn server or Vista (client).

It seems the major version and minor version are same for both:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833.aspx

So, is there any better alternative?

Comment: It's in the article you have posted? the wProductType differentiates between clients and servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't that same page you link give you the answer?

```
Windows Server 2008  OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION
Windows Vista        OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION
```

Just check the `wProductType` member against `VER_NT_WORKSTATION`

*edit*

Doesn't look like there's a way to get this without P/Invoke. `System.Environment.OSVersion` doesn't expose this level of detail, and though there is an `internal static class Win32Native` in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace in `mscorlib`, as far as I can tell from disassembly, there's nothing that uses, let alone exposes, `wProductType`.

I have found (but not tried) [this page on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/APIGetVersionEx.html).

Comment: seems it needs a pinvoke. is there a solution avoiding this pinvoke?

Comment: Thanks AakashM. Even I couldnt find one without P/Invoke. anyways, thanks for ur help

Comment: It can be done without pinvoke - via WMI. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

For Server,

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION
```

For Workstation

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI to find out windows version and all sorts of other system info as well.

Here is how to get a version string:

```
var osDetails = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<System.Management.ManagementObject>().First();
string version = osDetails.GetPropertyValue("Caption") as string;
```

this will return a string that reads something like: "Microsoft Windows XP Professional".

there are more properties there apart from Caption that can be used to retrieve version numbers, editions, architecture etc.:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=VS.85).aspx