# How to make Inno Setup installers install only on server versions of Windows

Tags: inno-setup

In the company I work we use Inno Setup to install our software products. The problem is that our software is only compatible with Windows Server versions. Like Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012.

What I'm trying to do is show a message and prevent the user to install in a non server versions. Like Windows 8 and 7 for instance.

I searched and is possible to check the Windows version using the Windows build number. But the build number of server versions of Windows are the same of some desktop. Is possible to check it here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes

Is there any way to make an installer that installs only on server versions of Windows using Inno Setup?

Since now, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test `TWindowsVersion.ProductType` returned by [`GetWindowsVersionEx` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex) from [`InitializeSetup` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents).

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  Result := True;

  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Log(Format('Product Type is %d', [Version.ProductType]));

  if Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION then
  begin
    MsgBox('This product can be installed on Windows Server only.', mbError, MB_OK);
    { Abort installer }
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

I've been defensive and test for `Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION`. Maybe you want to test `Version.ProductType <> VER_NT_SERVER` or `Version.ProductType <> VER_NT_SERVER and Version.ProductType <> VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER`.

For more details, refer to documentation of `wProductType` field of [`OSVERSIONINFOEX` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-osversioninfoexw).

See also [What is the simplest way to differentiate between Windows versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2370230/850848)

Comment: I used your code, but with a different validation: if Version.ProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION then ....

Tested even in Windows 10 and it works.